# How to store a line from expect_out(buffer) to a variable in tcl

Tags: bash, foreach, tcl, expect

For example, if the output ( in `expect_out(buffer)` )is

```
blah 
blh blah
asdjsudfsdf
```

how can I store the 2nd line to a variable? so far I have this:

```
foreach line [split $expect_out(buffer) "\n"] {
  if [lindex $line 1] {
    set variable $line
  }
}
```

But this does not work, it says the variable `variable` is undefined. I tried adding a counter, but that didn't work either. There has to be an easier way!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes there is an easier way:

```
set lines [split $expect_out(buffer) \n]
set variable [lindex $lines 1]
```

or in one line

```
set variable [lindex [split $expect_out(buffer) \n] 1]
```

Keep mindful you know what Tcl commands return: `split` returns a list. You then use `lindex` to find the 2nd element of the list.

Comment: Thanks! another quick question If I was to store everything but the last line, then would I count the lines first and then store everything except the last line? or is it all in one command?

Comment: @user2883071: `lrange $lines 0 end-1` might be rather useful if you're picking all but the last line. But then you'll still have a list of (the contents of) lines.